# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.play.core.review.b

Tags: java, android, review

In-app review api dialog working in android 9 and below but not working in android 10

below in error log

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.play.core.review.b
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.play.core.review.b
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3031)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2981)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2883)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3261)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1160)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8552)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:847)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:732)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:2074)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:646)
```

below is my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0' 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
 implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.2'
 implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
 implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Add this in question section

Comment: Use `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3'`

Comment: also try with 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3' but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and the problem was solve when I publish that new version on PlayStore!. Also you can try testing tracks in Google Play — Internal Testing, Alpha, or Beta if the app is not published yet